# Copy global functions to a map in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's say I have a jenkinsfile like this:

```
#!groovy
import ...
import ...
import ...

library identifier: 'A@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: '<the github link for A>'])

// ADD LIBRARY 'A' METHODS TO MAP HERE    

library identifier: 'B@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: '<the github link for B>'])

// ADD LIBRARY 'B' METHODS TO MAP HERE

// rest of the jenkinsfile
```

Is it possible to populate a map with the global variables that a library populates the scope with? What I mean is if I load library `A` and it has methods `foo, bar, baz` and I load library `B` and it has methods `foo, qux, abc`. Is it possible for me to have a map that works like this in the jenkinsfile?

```
global_map['A'].foo {
    asd = 'asd'
    qwe = 'qwe'
}

global_map['B'].foo {
    asd = 'asd'
    qwe = 'qwe'
}
```

Could this be possible as a plugin or a short snippet of code? My goal is to be able to run both versions of `foo` without one being overridden.

edit: to be clear, the functions `foo, bar, baz, quz, abc` are all in the `vars/` folder of both libraries.

Comment: Can't you assign the result of the `library` call to a variable? I.e., `libA = library iden...` etc?

Comment: You can, but that doesn't help with functions in the `vars` folder, since they're basically global singletons.